# Shouldn't Rosh Chodesh Iyar be a sad day?

Tags: rosh-chodesh-new-month, messianic-redemption, maseches-rosh-hashana

The Gemara in Rosh Hashana 10b-11a says

> בְּנִיסָן נִגְאֲלוּ בְּנִיסָן עֲתִידִין לִיגָּאֵל

Shouldn't that mean that when Rosh Chodesh Iyar comes and we, unfortunately, have not been redeemed, that there should be some level of sadness for that? Are there any sources that discuss such an idea?

Comment: For that matter I always claim the Pessach Sheni is a sad day.

Comment: I have heard that Reb Moshe used to be disappointed every year on Rosh Chodesh Iyar for this reason

Comment: Regarding the above comment, I heard the same thing too. Every Rosh Chodesh Iyar Rabbi Moshe Feinstein would be crying while all his students were celebrating because it was Rosh Chodesh. They asked him “rabbi why do you cry when you’re supposed to rejoice on Rosh Chodesh.” He then quoted the quote you brought and said something along the lines of “another Nissan gone by, another year of no mashiach”